# .htaccess issue | Codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I'm relatively new to Codeigniter and MVC. But, have successfully made two apps 'Locally'. While exploring, I found a way to remove 'Index.php' from the URL and also about custom routes. The .htaccess file that i have works like charm locally, but when trying to host it; there is a issue 505 *internal server issue*

Here is the first .htaccess code that i have (**works locally**) :-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# If your website begins from a folder e.g localhost/my_project then 
# you have to change it to: RewriteBase /my_project/
# If your site begins from the root e.g. example.local/ then
# let it as it is
RewriteBase /

# Protect application and system files from being viewed when the index.php is missing
RewriteCond $1 ^(application|system|private|logs)

# Rewrite to index.php/access_denied/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]

# Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|public|assets|css|js|images)

# No rewriting
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]

# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

When i use the code above there is an error. And, the app works only when .htaccess is removed. (I then have to use the inconvenient long URLs)

After a brief research and using different .htaccess without success, i asked one of my friends who has a Hosted CI app successfully running. He sends me a file which leads me the landing page without any problem; but, cant call any functions with/without using routing .i.e. If i use the custom routed URl (www.mySite.com/contact) then also it leads me to the landing page, the same with actual URL scheme (www.mySite.com/welcome/contact_page)

The new code here:-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Using this code shows me the landing page but i cannot navigate any further from there. When i try to call a function the landing page reloads. This, I think is because of the last error Handling Code (**ErrorDocument 404 /index.php**)

Does anyone know what the solution the problem might be??

questions

- Why doesnt the first .htaccess code work when hosted?
- What may be the issue with the second available .htaccess file??
- Do you guys have better .htaccess file? If yes, can you post it here??

Comment: What version of your CI using? If your using CI3 make sure file and class names only have the first letter upper case.

Comment: I'm using 2. And, first letter of the Class name are capitalized!!

Comment: Reading error message and [status code](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.6), something with http protocol version could go wrong. Check that too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `.htaccess` (**Codeigniter Recommended** )

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|image|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

---

In `application/config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
$config['index_page'] = ''; # Should be empty
```

---

> **And make sure Controller name, Model names are in proper way. Bcz Linux Host is an Case-Sensitive.**

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I have done all of these steps

Comment: @RohitNair so what happen??

Comment: Nothing! It's still the same!! I had done all these step earlier itself

Comment: Now doing some research on htaccess and how it works

Comment: Now way. This is the setup i used in mine

Comment: The program works when i changed my base_url to _http://www.mySite.tld/_  from  _http://mySite.tld/_. The second .htaccess file is now working fine! The issue with the first .htaccess is still prevalent!

Comment: @RohitNair if answer is helpful accept and vote up. Thank you

Comment: Answer to the second question is the one answer that i seek of.... Can you tell me what possibly is wrong in the first .htaccess file????  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Conditions:- 1)It works locally; 2)When hosted it throws an error 505. Which is related to.htaccess!

Comment: @RohitNair im not familiar with htacces much. In codeigniter uses the htacces which i provided for you. You can check it in docs of codeigniter. And some are writes there own htacces with the condition for there self. Its not works for all..